# version of padmin3 for postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently running pgadmin3 to connect to postgres. We upgraded from postgres 9.4 to 9.6. However pgadmin3 throws up an error message:
"
The server you are connecting to is not a version that is supported by this release of pgAdmin III.

pgAdmin III may not function as expected.

Supported server versions are 8.4 to 9.4.
"

Version:

```
$ pgadmin3 -v
01:30:45 PM: Debug: Adding duplicate image handler for 'PNG file'
pgAdmin III 1.20.0 Beta 2
```

An internet search brings says this that I need version 1.20. Any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: "*Any suggestions on what to do here?*" - download it? https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: which version? I have the latest version of pgadmin3.

Comment: The lastest pgAdmin 3 version is 1.22 And why don't you use pgAdmin 4?

Comment: Just downloaded that, and that seems to work.Thanks.

Comment: pgAdmin4 is really a huge step, ain't there a solution for pgAdmin3? I found https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAABt7R6Fzfq-q6%2BP4GC9evHcj_BjHvMhULW2aoEbOPXvpzFmSg%40mail.gmail.com, but don't like to install others things yet.